# is their a way to put a background and blur it without bluring all the content in the <div>?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a banner with a background image that is blured, but when I do it, all the banner is blured and not only the background image.

this is where I got so far, the first div is made so the blur dont go outside the banner, the second one is supposed to be the blur (the background-img is this div because its only a wireframe for multiple js integration) and the third one with the id: "guild-banner" is where the content is placed and is not finished yet since am stuck on the background problem:

HTML:

```
<div class="guild-banner-container">
    <div class="guild-background-logo" style="background: url('dum-guild.png')">
        <div class="guild-banner">
            <img src="dum-guild.png" alt="guild logo" class="big-guild-logo">
            <div>
                <h3 class="common-text guild-title">Challenge Saber</h3>
                <p class="common-text">Who’s the best in their category? Come to find out! <br> Features: Tech, Speed, Floor, Vibro, Techy Vibro, Stamina, Shitpost, Spirals...</p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div id="member-count-container">
                    <p class="common-text">120</p>
                    <img src="user.png" alt="user-img">
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="common-text">25</p>
                    <img src="favorite.png" alt="fav-img">
                </div>
                <div><button class="join-button">join request</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.guild-banner-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
}

.guild-background-logo {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    filter: blur(20px);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.guild-banner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    padding: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

even if I dont think the problem is in mi code, I hope this can help people to understand mi problem.

Answer (score 0):

use `backdrop-filter: blur(20px);`

```css
.guild-banner-container {
    overflow: hidden;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 170px;
}

.guild-background-logo {
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.guild-banner {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    padding: 16px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Hope this is helpful! sorry if i misplaced the `backdrop-filter`

Comment: I copied the exact css you gave and it doesnt help, I get no blur. I tried using the back-drop filter on the guild-banner and it worked

Comment: Glad this is helpful! you just misplacement the backdrop-filter